# How to Use an "if X or X" in a preg_match Statement

Tags: php, if-statement, preg-match

I'm looking to make a statement in PHP like this:

`if(preg_match("/apples/", $ref1, $matches)) OR if(preg_match("/oranges/", $ref1, $matches)) {
Then do something }`

Each of those above by themselves work just fine, but I can't figure out how to make it so that if either of them is true, then to perform the function I have beneath it.

Comment: If you show the real regexes we can give you a better solution.

Comment: fyi, your first expression will also match things like "pineapples".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple, use the logical OR operator:

```
if (expression || expression) { code }
```

For example, in your case:

```
if(
    preg_match("/qualifier 1/", $ref1, $matches) ||
    preg_match("/qualifier 2/", $ref1, $matches)
) {
    do_something();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked perfectly...I also feel like an idiot now, haha.

Answer (score 31):

Use the `|` to select one value or the other. You can use it multiple times.

```
preg_match("/(apples|oranges|bananas)/", $ref1, $matches)
```

**EDIT:** This post made me hungry.

Comment: you obviously lead a healthy lifestyle!

Answer (score 14):

To group your patterns and capture the result in `$matches`:

```
preg_match('/(apples|oranges)/', $ref1, $matches)
```

To group your patterns *without* capturing the result in `$matches` (most relevant if you're doing other parenthesis capturing and don't want this to interfere):

```
preg_match('/(?:apples|oranges)/', $ref1, $matches)
```